# Getting CORS error trying to hit server from same server

Tags: nginx, cors

I have a docker container running my backend on port 7958. On the same instance I have a svelte front end + backend running on port 5173.
The front end makes a POST request to my domain/login, and Im getting CORS error.
I tried add allow-cross origin headers on both nginx and my svelte server, but nothing gives.

I shared an image of what the request/response looks like

My Nginx config

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=retarded.dev_ratelimit:10m rate=1r/s;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name retarded.dev;
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name retarded.dev;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/retarded.dev/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/retarded.dev/privkey.pem;

    # Various TLS hardening settings
    # https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets on;
    ssl_stapling on;

  # Hide nginx version
    server_tokens off;

    # Enable compression for JS/CSS/HTML bundle, for improved client load times.
    # It might be nice to compress JSON, but leaving that out to protect against potential
    # compression+encryption information leak attacks like BREACH.
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;

    # Only connect to this site via HTTPS for the two years
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000";

    # Various content security headers
    add_header Referrer-Policy "unsafe-url";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

 add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*";

    # Upload limit for pictrs
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    # frontend
    location / {
      # The default ports:
      # lemmy_ui_port: 1235
      # lemmy_port: 8536
      set $proxpass "http://0.0.0.0:5173";
      if ($http_accept ~ "^application/.*$") {
        set $proxpass "http://0.0.0.0:7958";
      }
      if ($request_method = POST) {
        #set $proxpass "http://0.0.0.0:7958";

  proxy_pass $proxpass;

      rewrite ^(.+)/+$ $1 permanent;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*";
      # Send actual client IP upstream
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     #proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # backend
    # backend
    location ~ ^/(api|pictrs|feeds|nodeinfo|.well-known) {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:7958;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

      # Rate limit
      limit_req zone=retarded.dev_ratelimit burst=30 nodelay;

      # Add IP forwarding headers
#proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

[image: I tried add allow-cross origin headers on both nginx and my svelte server, but nothing gives.]

Comment: There are no CORS-related headers for `/api` in nginX - are you setting them in your backend application ?

Comment: Im not calling /api. I am calling /apus from my front end client to my backend server hosted on :5173. There is another backend server serving /api on : and 7958